# Extract Data from SQL to Excel without overwriting the previous Data

Tags: sql, ssis

I was able to use SQL Server Agent to create a job that extract Data from SQL Server 2008 to Excel Format Daily. However, is there anyway to create a job that keep all the extracts separately without overwrite the previous files? I would really much appreciated your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When using OLE DB/Jet data provider for Excel, there is a way to specify the target worksheet name. A worksheet in Excel is a rough equivalent of a database table. One option is to use a different worksheet name each time (say, based on a current date). Another option would be to append the data to the existing worksheet, if that's what you're after. If SQL Server Agent job does not allow you to do something like that, then you may want to create a small app instead.

Comment: I have already looked into inserting a new worksheet for every extract. However, this is not what I would like to do. In order to keep track of all the data exported, I would prefer to have the data dump in different files every time it extracts.

Comment: I see. A good rule of thumb: if some technological deficiency gets in your way, try to think out of the box and find an alternative. If SQL Server Agent doesn't let you do something like choosing a different file name every time it runs a job, I would ditch it for this particular task, and write a small app instead, then run it using Task Scheduler. More freedom and less headache that way.

Answer (score 0):

While Copying from OLEDB to Excel, You can dynamically pass the file name through the expressions based on the Datetime.

Ex: Filepath+Date1_mmddyy_hhmmss

Every time the file generates, It will create a file with new file name and Excel file should be passed as an expression.

Comment: Let me know if you need more explanation.